# Two different solutions for the expression of potential energy of a uniformly charged solid sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential-energy

I am a bit confused because I did some rigorous derivation of potential energy of a uniformly charged solid sphere and got two different solutions.(Sorry for the long exercise)

Now have a look at my 1st approach:-
[image: 1st approach in derivation of potential energy of uniformly charged solid sphere]

I got the general result in my 1st approach which can easily be found in any textbook.

Now have a look at my 2nd approach:-
[image: 2nd approach in derivation of potential energy of a uniformly charged solid sphere]

I got two different results and the second expression is numerically less than the first expression.I want to ask about this ambiguity  of two different results for the same problem. I assumed the reference point to be infinity in both derivations and the solid spheres are non conducting.

Comment: Have you taken into account that potential energy is only defined up to an arbitrarily defined reference level? If this level is different for the two derivations, then it's no surprise if the numerical values are different. I haven't looked at your derivations in detail because the photos are a bit hard to read, so please ignore this comment if you already covered that possibility.

Comment: @Cuspy Code.See I have edited it.

Comment: @Cuspy Code please see the derivation and help me out. Can you attract users to help me to solve this ambiguity?

Comment: Please make your question one cohesive question. Edit histories are available for those who are interested. Also please don't add superfluous text to your question asking people to answer your question. The fact that you have asked the question shows readers that you want it to be answered.

Comment: Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your work instead of posting pictures that are harder to look at and read.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens I want it to be answered.

Comment: Please read my first comment

Answer (score 2):

In your second derivation, you considered the energy of the electric field present inside the solid sphere but forgot to consider the energy carried by the electric field present outside the boundary of the sphere.

Changing the limits to $0→∞$ in the integral won't work because the electric field varies differently outside the charged sphere. It varies as: $$E=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_o}\frac{Q}{r^2}\qquad (r≥R)$$
This electric field is present everywhere outside the sphere (its influence goes on until infinity).

Now, for calculating the energy of this outside field, use the same method you did to find the energy inside the sphere but this time use the above electric field function and integrate from $R→∞$. If done correctly, you should get $U(outside)=\frac{k}{2}\frac{Q^2}{R}$. Adding this to your already calculated energy inside  the sphere, you should get the total potential energy or self energy of a uniformly charged solid sphere.

If something is unclear please feel free to point it out.